# subquery in WHERE clause with inverted Q object

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I have two models, where one refers to another:

```
class A(models.Model):                                                          

    variable = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)                   
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='as', related_query_name="a") 


class B(models.Model):
    pass
```

I would like to follow backward the relation while filtering on `variable`:

```
B.objects.filter(~Q(a__variable))
```

**Problem:**
This yields an extra subquery in the `where` clause:

```
'SELECT "b"."id" FROM "b" WHERE NOT ("b"."id" IN (SELECT U1."b_id" FROM "a" U1 WHERE U1."variable" = True))'
```

On the other hand, when not inverting the Q expression

```
B.objects.filter(Q(a__variable))
```

the join is done "correctly", i.e. outside the `where` clause:

```
'SELECT "b"."id" FROM "b" INNER JOIN "a" ON ("b"."id" = "a"."b_id") WHERE "a"."variable" = True'
```

**NOTE:** I used a boolean only as an example (which I could turn into `False`)

I'm using django 2.0.4 and postgres 9.6.2

Comment: This is *expected behavior*. Django has specified that a filter on a related model, is done with an *existential* quantifier. The negation of a existential quantifier is a universal quantifier with the negated predicate.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/657931/26494

Comment: For your case you can use `B.objects.filter(a__variable=False)` (or strictly speaking `B.objects.filter(Q(a__variable=None) | Q(a__variable=False))`) this is *not the same* as `B.objects.filter(Q(a__variable=True))`

Comment: But changing `a__variable=False` to `a__variable=True` should be the same as putting an invert in front of the Q expression. And why does this work if I follow the reference in the forward direction, i.e. `A.object.filter(Q(b__another_var=True))`?

Comment: no, since this would make it not sound with "*predicate logic*". Imagine that there are two related `A`s, one with `variable=True`, and one with `variable=False`, you expect the query `B.objects.filter(~Q(a__variable=True))` to contain exactly the `B`s that did *not* occur in the query `B.objects.filter(Q(a___variable=True))` (since you inverted the condition), but here that `B` object will occur in *both* querysets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** the *negation* of "all `B` objects with a related `A` object with `variable = True`" is *not* the query "*all `B` objects with a related `A` object with `variable = False`".

You can query on this like:

```
B.objects.filter(a__variable=False)
```

or in case the field is `NULL`-able:

```
B.objects.filter(Q(a__variable=None) | Q(a__variable=False))
```

## Background: negating existentially quantified expressions

This is **expected** behavior. Since if you query a *related* model in a one-to-many fashion, the designers of the Django ORM have picked the *existential quantifier ∃* over the *universal quantifier ∀*. There is no *inherent best choice*, although I think most queries humans will perform are *existentially* quantified*.

An existential quantifier means "there exists", so if you write `B.objects.filter(a__variable=True)`, you ask for `B` objects where "*there exists* a related `A` object with `variable=True`".

But the *negation* of this is *not* the list of `B` objects "where *there exists* a related `A` object with `variable=False`" (let us ignore the `NULL` vase for now). Indeed a `B` object that has two related `A` objects, one with `variable = True`, and one with `variable = False` would *occur* in both the original variant, and its negation.

The negation of a *existentially quantified* requirement, is the *univerally quantified variant of the negation of that predicate*. Or in mathematics:

¬∃*x*: P(x) ↔ ∀*x*: ¬ P(x)

It thus means that the negation of the query "*All `B` objects for which there exists an `A` with `variable=True`*", is the query "*All `B` objects for which *all* related `A` objects have a `variable` that is *not* `B`*". Notice the *all* in the second query. It thus means that for each row in the `A` table, we need to "iterate" over the related "B" objects, to check if all these `variable`s are *not* `True`. This is not really "tailored" for `JOIN`s. In the case of a `BooleanField` we *could* do that with a `GROUP BY` and a `MAX(..)` to check if at least one such `TRUE` exists, and thus constrain it that this is *not* `TRUE`. Something like:

```
SELECT b.*, MAX(a.variable) AS mx
FROM b
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING mx = FALSE OR mx IS NULL
```

But this "*trick*" would require some "advanced" *tiling* by the Django ORM query builder. This will perhaps in future versions eventually get supported, but regardless, the efficiency will approximately be the same.